# Matrix Interpretation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Given for e.g

```
val =
   200   202   189   188   189   175   175   175
   200   203   198   188   189   182   178   175
   203   200   200   195   200   187   185   175
   200   200   200   200   197   187   187   187
   200   205   200   200   195   188   187   175
   200   200   200   200   200   190   187   175
   205   200   199   200   191   187   187   175
   210   200   200   200   188   185   187   186
```

and I execute `asd = dct2(val)` i.e 2-D Discrete Cosine transform which gives

```
asd =

   1.0e+03 *

    1.5389    0.0650   -0.0118    0.0036    0.0014    0.0023   -0.0080    0.0049
   -0.0159    0.0034    0.0020    0.0004   -0.0002   -0.0112   -0.0021    0.0033
   -0.0123    0.0064    0.0115   -0.0008    0.0031    0.0004    0.0013   -0.0019
   -0.0078    0.0026   -0.0044    0.0023   -0.0024   -0.0026   -0.0046   -0.0015
    0.0004   -0.0021    0.0066   -0.0054    0.0044   -0.0005   -0.0015   -0.0035
    0.0001   -0.0030   -0.0008    0.0003    0.0042    0.0012   -0.0011    0.0003
    0.0025   -0.0016   -0.0032    0.0030    0.0032   -0.0007   -0.0007    0.0029
   -0.0015    0.0047   -0.0017    0.0036   -0.0024    0.0019   -0.0026    0.0001
```

`asd` as expected is an `8 X 8` matrix using `size(asd)` but
I just need some clarification on the `1.0e+03 *` hanging before the 1st line of matrix `asd`.what does it signify? Are my matrix elements a multiple of/suffixed by `1.0e+03 *`?

Comment: Yes, they are. it is a convenient way of representing large/small numbers.

Comment: Also see the `format` function. Default formatting of numbers are `format short`

Comment: try `format long g` if you are confused.

Comment: @AnderBiguri  Yeah the `format long` cleared it up. Nice..